# How to mix colors like in reality?

Tags: materials, shaders, color

I'd like to mix the colors to get the exact color that you would get in reality, I realize that RGB is a completely different system, but I was wondering if anyone has experience with this.
In the picture obviously I get the White being an RGB system is very obvious. I'm trying to study this a bit but I don't know if I'm on the right way

Further clarification:
I would like to get the colors that would be obtained in reality (I think by subtractive synthesis) but I don't know this study very well, and I'd like to create a node that does this

[image]

Comment: Your node setup is most likely not what you wanted, to get "white", the right mix node will have to have a value of `0.666`. Other than that, could you give us more insight of how colors are mixed in *reality*? What would mixing red and blue give e.g.

Comment: @Leander Hi, maybe I'll explain myself, white is obtained by mixing RGB colors, this is clear. I would rather get the colors that are obtained in reality as if they were mixing 3 real paints of that color

Comment: @Leander I think you should get a shade very close to black, more on brown, but I'm not a specialist in this studio, so I'd like to learn how to do something like this

Comment: Read [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/53973/how-to-simulate-paint-mixing)? What is your actual end goal. Why is just picking a color not a good option?

Comment: What you want is the **multiply** mode of the MixRGB node. You will notice though, that multiplying red and blue will result in black. This would happen in real life as well if your colors were pure red and black. But in real life, colors contain a range wavelengths and are already mixes themselves. You can't simulate that with simple RGB inputs.

Comment: @Leander Yes the link talks about what I mean, basically I want to get a knot (But it won't be easy) to manage the colors like in reality, for example I would like to obtain a derivative mixture of various colors (as if building a real paint)

Comment: Then you would have to know the spectral setup of your colors, right? These can't be represented by RGB values you plug into the mix. Blender most probably isn't the software for this problem.

Comment: @Leander Thanks for the answer, but I'd like to recreate a trick that does this, for example if you say the Mix Set to Multiply, you get the black setting the mix to the value 1.0 while I believe that in reality it is closer to 0.9, but not I am sure of this, so I was looking for an answer that would indicate a path to follow to reach this